# How do I override a particular extension on a .gitignore file?

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

I have a rule in the .gitignore file of my GitHub repo to ignore all .jar files that will come up during development.

Now, I am working on an upgrade task, which has some Jar files that need to go into the remote repository. I can remove the rule from the .gitignore file but I will have to cherry-pick each relevant jar file among 100 more Jars that were been ignored previously.

The work I am doing is isolated to a few folders and subfolders on the repo.

There must be some easier way to achieve this goal. Googling won't help because I don't even know what I should be searching for.

From the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60558023/14310825, I have tried to try to override that rule. For example, if my project directory looks like this.

[image: ProjectFolderStructure]

This is the real folder structure of my local, .git and .gitignore are present inside the custom folder [invisible here]

and my .gitignore looks like this:

```
# Compiled class file
*.class

# Log file
*.log

# BlueJ files
*.ctxt

# Mobile Tools for Java (J2ME)
.mtj.tmp/

# Package Files #
*.jar
!solr-commerce-plugins*.jar
*.war
*.nar
*.ear
*.zip
*.tar.gz
*.rar

# virtual machine crash logs, see http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_hotspot.xml
hs_err_pid*


##############################
## Eclipse
##############################
.metadata
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib
.loadpath
.factorypath
eclipsebin

##############################
## OS X
##############################
.DS_Store       

##############################
## Maven
##############################
target/
pom.xml.tag
pom.xml.releaseBackup
pom.xml.versionsBackup
pom.xml.next
pom.xml.bak
release.properties
dependency-reduced-pom.xml
*build.number
.mvn/timing.properties
.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar

##############################
## SAP CC
##############################
/core-customize/c4c-integration
/core-customize/licenses
/core-customize/hybris/temp
/core-customize/installer
/core-customize/hybris/log
/core-customize/hybris/data
/core-customize/hybris/bin/platform
/core-customize/hybris/bin/modules
/core-customize/hybris/bin/dummy.txt
/core-customize/README
/core-customize/SIGNATURE.SMF
/core-customize/build-tools
*classes/
/core-customize/hybris/bin/custom/avantor*/**/*jalo/
*addonsrc/
*addons/
*addontestsrc/
*_ui/
!*rhino-1.7.7.jar
!*wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar
*commonwebsrc/
*gensrc/
/core-customize/hybris/config/backup
/core-customize/hybris/config/tomcat
/core-customize/hybris/config/solr/instances/default/*
!/core-customize/hybris/config/solr/instances/default/configsets
core-customize/hybris/config/solr/instances/default/configsets/default/conf/*
!/core-customize/hybris/config/solr/instances/default/configsets/default/conf/*.xml
!/core-customize/hybris/config/solr/instances/default/configsets/default/conf/lang
/core-customize/hybris/config/orbeon
/core-customize/hybris/config/licence
/core-customize/hybris/config/security
/core-customize/hybris/config/local.properties

# Exclude build-regenerated misc files
/core-customize/hybris/bin/custom/**/build.xml
extensioninfo.xsd
beans.xsd
items.xsd
platformhome.properties
*-webtestclasses.xml
*-testclasses.xml
.lastupdate
core-customize/hybris/bin/custom/avantor/avantorcore/.classpath
*node_modules/
*.rush/
*dist/
```

`\custom\otmmaddon\bin\otmmaddonserver.jar` and `\custom\otmmaddonbackoffice\bin\otmmaddonbackofficeserver.jar`
are the jars I need to add to the commit along with two more Jar file for OTMMsmartedit and OTMMws having similar folder structure

what I did was add this two lines on the git ignore

```
!\custom\otmmaddon\bin\**\.jar
!\custom\otmmaddonbackoffice\**\*.js
```

Git is still ignoring the files.

Please note that I am working on a Java-Springboot project, the above is an example of what issues I am facing and what I am expecting. I do not want to ignore any .jar files in some directories of my repo

Comment: Your folder is named ExtrasJS not Extras

Comment: This is a pure git question. No need for the java and js tags.

Comment: You should be able to create a `.gitignore` file in the directories where you want to permit tracking of the `.jar` files.  That file should contain `!*.jar` to permit any `.jar` file in the directory (and its sub-directories) to be tracked.

Comment: "I do not want to ignore any .jar files in some directories of my repo" would you please take time to give an example that looks closer to your actual situation ?

Comment: @Sören the JS was just an example, My real project structure is different and quite large

Comment: In that case, please post your **real** directory structure and your **real** .gitignore.

Comment: @Sören Posting my real Project directory structure may violate my NDA, I do not want to post any confidential info on a public forum.

Comment: @LeGEC Overall I want git to ignore .jar files except for one or two directories where I am currently working on

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can you elaborate or point me to any documentation?

Comment: In that case, please read [mre]

Comment: You can read about how the `.gitignore` files work in the [Git Book](https://book.git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).  If there's a `.gitignore` file in your directory `bootstrap/js/Extras` that contains `!*.js`, Git should not ignore the `.js` files in  `Extras` or its sub-directories.

Comment: Your problem with your 'ignore' lines is that you've included `bootstrap/` at the start, but there's no subdirectory `bootstrap` that those lines apply to.  You need to replace `!bootstrap/css/Extras/*.css` with `!css/Extras/**/*.css`, and similarly for `.js` files. Personally, I'd put the rule in a lower-level `.gitignore` file as I noted in my previous comments, but I can see a case for have all the rules at the top-level.  I think it is harder to manage, but that could be a project-wide decision that takes more effort to undo than to add the right rules to the top-level `.gitignore` file.

Comment: @Sören I have taken an approval from concerning person and has updated how my actual project structure looks like now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>*Transcribing edited forms of my comments ([[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77996872/how-do-i-override-a-particular-extension-on-a-gitignore-file?#comment137505027_77996872)] [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77996872/how-do-i-override-a-particular-extension-on-a-gitignore-file?#comment137513001_77996872)] [[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77996872/how-do-i-override-a-particular-extension-on-a-gitignore-file?#comment137515541_77996872)]) into an answer.*</sup>

It's interesting that the text of the question mentions `.jar` files but the example only covers `.js` and `.css` files.

---

> You should be able to create a `.gitignore` file in the directories where you want to permit tracking of the `.jar` files. That file should contain `!*.jar` to permit any `.jar` file in the directory (and its sub-directories) to be tracked.

---

> You can read about how the .gitignore files work in the Git Book's manual page for [`gitignore`](https://book.git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). If there's a `.gitignore` file in your directory `bootstrap/js/Extras` that contains `!*.js`, Git should not ignore the `.js` files in `Extras` or its sub-directories.

---

> Your problem with your 'ignore' lines is that you've included `bootstrap/` at the start:
>
> ```
> !bootstrap/css/Extras/*.css
> !bootstrap/js/Extras/**/*.js
> ```
>
> but there's no subdirectory `bootstrap` that those lines apply to. You need to replace these lines with:
>
> ```
> !css/Extras/**/*.css
> ```
>
> and similarly for `.js` files and `.jar` files.  You don't need both lines because the `/**/` notation is explicitly documented at the linked page as matching *zero* or more directory levels:
>
> - A slash followed by two consecutive asterisks then a slash matches zero or more directories. For example, "a/**/b" matches "a/b", "a/x/b", "a/x/y/b" and so on.
>
> Personally, I'd put the rule in a lower-level `.gitignore` file, as I noted previously.  However, I can see a case for having all the rules at the top level. I think it is harder to manage, but that could be a project-wide decision that takes more effort to undo than to add the right rules to the top-level `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Pretty sure that bootstrap is also "just an example"

Comment: @Sören — yes, but the Git repo is in `bootstrap/.git`, so it is important that the names in the `.gitignore` file do not start with `bootstrap/`.  That explains why the notation in the question was not working, given the scenario in the question.  If the information in the question is inaccurate, then it is hard to give an accurate answer.

Comment: Thanks, @JonathanLeffler, the .gitignore in the subdirectories as you suggested works and I can see the changes currently on git status. 
Also, I have tried to provide a more accurate picture of my project directory to avoid confusion. 
But if I make changes on the central .gitignore (which will be preferred) I do not see my changes again I have put the.
Note: The Git Repo and the project repo are junction-linked which is more confusing to me. (IDK if this is relevent but I just let you know)